# Dialog: Show menu after option has been executed

Tags: linux, bash, dialog

I hope someone can help me out with my query.

I would like to achieve the same results as the code below but using dialog instead.

```
#!/bin/bash
PS3='Please enter your choice: '
options=("Option 1" "Option 2" "Option3" "Quit")
select opt in "${options[@]}"
do
    case $opt in
        "Option 1")
            sudo apt-get update
            ;;
        "Option 2")
            echo "you chose choice 2"
            ;;
        "Option 3")
            echo "you chose choice 3"
            ;;
        "Quit")
            break
            ;;
        *) echo invalid option;;
    esac
done
```

Please see below the code for dialog:

```
#!/bin/bash

HEIGHT=15
WIDTH=40
CHOICE_HEIGHT=4
BACKTITLE="Backtitle here"
TITLE="Title here"
MENU="Choose one of the following options:"

OPTIONS=(1 "Option 1"
         2 "Option 2"
         3 "Option 3")

CHOICE=$(dialog --clear \
                --backtitle "$BACKTITLE" \
                --title "$TITLE" \
                --menu "$MENU" \
                $HEIGHT $WIDTH $CHOICE_HEIGHT \
                "${OPTIONS[@]}" \
                2>&1 >/dev/tty)

clear
case $CHOICE in
        1)
          sudo apt-get update
             ;;
        2)
            echo "You chose Option 2"
            ;;
        3)
            echo "You chose Option 3"
           ;;
esac
```

Basically after selecting option 1 for example I would like to get prompted with the same menu again.

Many thanks in advance for your kind help.

Kind regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert the dialog section into a while loop

```
#!/bin/bash

HEIGHT=15
WIDTH=40
CHOICE_HEIGHT=4
BACKTITLE="Backtitle here"
TITLE="Title here"
MENU="Choose one of the following options:"

OPTIONS=(1 "Option 1"
         2 "Option 2"
         3 "Option 3"
         4 "Quit")

while [ "$CHOICE" -ne 4 ]; do
    CHOICE=$(dialog --clear \
                    --backtitle "$BACKTITLE" \
                    --title "$TITLE" \
                    --menu "$MENU" \
                    $HEIGHT $WIDTH $CHOICE_HEIGHT \
                    "${OPTIONS[@]}" \
                    2>&1 >/dev/tty)

    clear
    case $CHOICE in
            1)
                sudo apt-get update
                ;;
            2)
                echo "You chose Option 2"
                ;;
            3)
                echo "You chose Option 3"
                ;;
    esac
done
```

Comment: I have tried your code, but I am getting this error message:

Comment: ./test.sh: line 15: [: -ne: unary operator expected

Comment: Any idea what it could be please?

Comment: You're right, my bad.
The cause for this is that CHOICE isn't defined at the first loop, so it returns an empy string. Then you get [ "" -ne 4 ] which is an invalid expression. You can either wrap $CHOICE with "" as you did, or predefine it (e.g. to 0), and avoid this error. In general, it's a better habit to enclose your variable with "". I'll fix the answer as well.

Comment: Thanks for updating your post, however " is still missing at the end of "$CHOICE" -ne 4

Comment: There's no need for " around the 4 as well. The problem was that after expansion of the variable (means, substituting its value), you got the expression [ -ne 4 ], which is invalid, because -ne expects two arguments. However, the "4" will always be expressed as... 4, there's no way it be evaluated to "nothing" like $CHOICE.

Comment: I'd like to note that I put the line `TERMINAL=$(tty)` at the top of my script and then in the `CHOICE` variable definition I changed `2>&1 >/dev/tty` to `2>&1 >$TERMINAL` to avoid redirection issues if the script was run in a different terminal context.

Answer (score 1):

Great I found it: "" where missing in

```
$CHOICE -ne 4
```

So the correct line is:

```
while [ "$CHOICE -ne 4" ]; do
```

Thanks a lot for that! Many appreciated!